# Cakephp AND constraint for array in query operation

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a Table schedules that needs to be joined in my Query.

```
$joins[] = array(
    'table' => 'schedules',
    'alias' => 'Schedule',
    'conditions' => array(
         'Schedule.provider_id = Provider.id',
         'Schedule.endtime > "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"',
         'Schedule.starttime' => $startTimes,
    ),
    'type' => 'INNER'
);
```

`$starttimes`is an array consisting of DateTime Objects.
Providers can have multiple schedules and I want to get all providers, which match at least all starttimes from the `$starttimes`array.

Comment: My question would be, _why_? Your `starttime` column can only have one of the values, so using multiple `AND` will never match anything (unless all dates are the same).

Comment: Maybe I should have made it more clear in my question, and my wrong mysql statment is misleading.
 Every provider has multiple rows in the schedules table, and I want to get all providers which have rows with at least all the times in the `$starttimes` array.

Comment: Now that's something totally different. Please [**update your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38694268/edit) with these details, and add proper sample SQL if you know what it should look like, otherwise just remove the current SQL.

Comment: I don't have time for an answer now, gotta go, but maybe you can answer it yourself with the following hint: I think you may be looking for something like `GROUP BY Provider.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Schedule.id) = :startTimesCount`

Comment: Thank you very much. That last comment actually solved the problem

Comment: Good to hear that, maybe you can add your solution as an answer here and accept it later on, so that it can help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) I got the solution. What I was missing was the group stetement:

```
$group = 'Provider.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Schedule.id) = ' . count($startTimes);
```